# I need the BIRT.war that is compatible with Java 17 and Tomcat 10

Tags: java, eclipse, birt, tomcat10

I need the Birt.war that is compatible with Java 17 and Tomcat 10. We have a birt.war file but it worked with Java 8 and its ancient. I need a new one or preferably the project so I can build it myself. All the links I see for the BIRT WAR say file unavailable. Can some one please help me by posting a link to a BIRT WAR that will work with Java 17 or any any Java past 9.

I have been searching the internet for about a week. I tried using the old WAR and I got javax errors, because Java 17 doesn't have javax anymore.